# Most efficient way to calculate correlation matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, correlation, pearson

I need to calculate the sales correlation of 5000 products which will results in 5000 by 5000 correlation matrix. I am trying to accomplish this in pandas using df.corr() but it is causing memory issues. Any ideas of more efficient ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use np.corrcoef...I was able to process the matrix in under a minute using this.